# Multiple user profile templates based on url in Drupal 7, theming user profile

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Used user-profile.tpl.php to customize user profile page.

Need to use a custom template when accessing urls like 'user/3/photo' or 'user/5/photo'.

How to use multiple user profile templates based on path / url in Drupal 7? What name should I use for the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what module you're using to generate the 'user/X/photo' pages, so it's difficult to tell you exactly what template file to use. However, when in doubt about how to theme something in Drupal, install the [Theme Developer module](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer). It will allow you to see what theme file or function is currently outputting a specific page or area of the page, as well as what files or functions can be used to override it. See the [screencast](http://drupal.org/node/209561) for more detailed information.

Comment: p.s. - You may also want to check out the Drupal Answers Beta site. The more people who use it, the better chance it has of making it past beta: http://drupal.stackexchange.com

Comment: The Core Templates handbook page (http://drupal.org/node/190815) shows that there's also a user-picture.tpl.php template file: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user-picture.tpl.php/7 That may be what you're looking for. If not, I'd still recommend installing the Theme Developer module, in case it lists some alternatives. You could add some logic to check the arg() function for the URL you're on and change the template accordingly, but it's probably better to add a custom template suggestion: http://drupal.org/node/223440#custom-suggestions